# Installed ruby gem(NMatrix) not showing in irb

Tags: permissions, rubygems, rvm

I have installed ruby gem nmatrix with the command below:

> sudo gem install nmatrix

I have installed it in ubuntu 12.04 . My gem env is as below:

```html
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.25
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-05-15 patchlevel 429) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://gems.github.com/", "http://rubygems.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.github.com/
     - http://rubygems.org
```

Now when I go to irb and run code as below,to use NMatrix it gives error as :

```html
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> false
irb(main):002:0> require 'nmatrix'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- nmatrix
 from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from (irb):2
 from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>
```

So what should I do to use nMatrix gem I just installed. Also when i do

> gem list

It is not showing nmatrix gem.

Doing

> sudo gem list

only shows nmatrix gem.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried installing nmatrix with `gem install nmatrix` and without the `sudo`? You should also verify that you're using the same Ruby version between the superuser and your regular user account. I recommend using rbenv or something similar.

Comment: gem install nmatrix and without the sudo, gave me permission denied error. So I have to do sudo. I was using rvm.

Comment: Yes, so that's your problem. `rvm` and `rbenv` both install for the local user, but you're trying to install nmatrix for the super-user, which means not in the local user's Ruby installation. I don't think this is an NMatrix problem. Are you able to install other gems? I'd need to see the exact permission denied error to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The error is "~$ gem install nmatrix
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429 directory."/

Comment: I re-tagged your question with rvm and permissions. I'd suggest looking around for this error with other gems and people using rvm, because others have likely had this problem before. I think I have in the past, but it's been too long for me to easily help. =/